# Symfony2 + Assetic: watch on OSX is slow

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I'm currently working on a Symfony 2 project, using Assetic for assets management.

On Mac OSX (Mavericks 10.9 and ML 10.8), the watcher (`--watch` command) is very slow to detect modifications.
On Linux, it's leveraging inotify to speed it up.

I would like to know if there is there a way to improve Assetic's performance on OSX before considering switching to another tool like Grunt to manage my assets while developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We actually came up with a solution on this one.

The issue was that our Assetic Bundle was running Lurker (https://github.com/henrikbjorn/Lurker) inside Assetic.

Simply disable it and rely only on Assetic has solved our issue.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: @arnaudbreton is your assetic bundle non standard? How did you disable 'lurker'?